# How to search a char array for a specific char?

Tags: java, arrays

Lets say I have a char array that contains the sequences of chars: "robots laser car"
I want to search for spaces in this char array in order to identify each separate word. I wanted to do something like this pseudocode below:

for lengthOfArray
    if array[i].equals(" ")
        doSomething();

But I cant find array methods to that comparison.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but I'll throw it out there anyway: if you have a `String` instead of a `char` array, you can split by whitespace to get an array of strings containing the separate words.

```
String s = new String(array);
String[] words = s.split("\\s+");
// words = { "robots", "laser", "car" }
```

The `\s+` regular expression matches one or more whitespace characters (space, carriage return, etc.), so the string will be split on any whitespace.

Comment: Not what I was looking for, but it seems way more clean and efficient.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Or the old fashioned way

```
for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
    if(' ' == array[i]){
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you just want something like the following that loops through and does something when it gets to a space?

```
for(char c : "robots laser car".toCharArray()) {
    if(c==' ') {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over the words inside a string, do this:

```
for (String word : new String(charArray).split("\\s+")){
    doSomething(word); // Such as System.out.println(word);
}
```